# Volley is unable to cinnect with server

Tags: php, android, database, database-connection, android-volley

I'm trying to connect my Android app to a database,
I tried to connect it the localhost and everything went okay,
but when I tried to connect it with a PHP file on server it showed me a volley error
I think there's a problem in the URL but I don't know what it should be!

This worked well

```
String URL = "http:/10.0.2.2//ServerConnect/GetIformation.php"
```

But this didn't work

```
String URL = "http://raghad.hostkda.com/phptest.php";
```

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace, Also, "http://raghad.hostkda.com/phptest.php"; doesnot return a valid json

Comment: How can we guess without seeing your code ?

Comment: the problem is with the url , when you enter to it you'll see the results which mean the php file is working , but the url is not working when I put it in the code

Comment: like when we enter the local host we put 10.0.2.2 , what should I put in the URL when I deal with remote server

Answer (score 0):

The text in link you provided is not a valid JSON.

Remove `http: //raghad.hostkda.com/phptest.php` from the end of the file.

Comment: The provided link gives a valid JSON. (Maybe op changed something?)

Comment: it still can't connect :(